# How to pad or extend the most significant bit (bit 23) into bits 24 through 31

Tags: c

I want to know, how could I extend the most significant bit (bit 23) into bits 24 through 31? How could I do that in C code? I am using C code to program Nios II.

I was thinking of using bit shifting operation but not knowing in details how by using bit shifting operation, the above could be achieved, any link or resource is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if( n & (1 << 23)) n |= 0xff000000;`

Comment: Can there already be something in these bits, or are they guaranteed to be all 0 (or -- why not? -- 1)?

Answer (score 4):

As Carl said, right shift if implementation defined.  You can use other binary operators that will always work:

```
if (0 != (0x00800000 & x))   //test if bit 23 is set
{
    x |= 0xFF000000;   //set bits 24-31
}
else
{
    x &= 0x00FFFFFF;  //clear bits 24-31
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The C right-shift operator has implementation-defined behaviour when right-shifting. Since Nios II [has an arithmetic right-shift instruction](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii51017.pdf), you can likely simply do:

```
x = (x << 8) >> 8;
```

Double check the output assembly to be sure it uses an instruction from the `sra` family.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on [@IronMensan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971607/2410359) which relies on the reasonable assumption that the integer being modified is 32 bits.

The following only affects bit 24-31, even if the integer is wider.

```
#define Mask2431 (0xFF000000)
#define Bit23    (0x800000)

some_int |= Mask2431; 
if (!(some_int & Bit23)) 
  some_int ^= Mask2431;
```

The following affects bit 24 and all higher even when using wider than a 32-bit integer:

```
#define Mask24 (0xFFFFFF)
#define Bit23    (0x800000)

some_int &= Mask24;
if (some_int & Bit23) 
  some_int = ~some_int ^ Mask24;
```